# How to replace `0` zeros only in date and month using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to replace the date and month's zeros to empty value. but now including year getting updated. how to do this?

I find my approach is very long. Anyone show me shortest way to do this?

here is my try:

```js
var date = "04/07/2019".replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$3/$2/$1").replace(/0/g, '').split('/').join(',');
console.log(date); // 219,7,4 !!?
```

Comment: Replace needs to be leading zero, not any zero

Comment: Maybe `.replace( /(?:0?(\d)|(\d{2}))\/(?:0?(\d)|(\d{2}))\/(\d{4})/, "$5,$3$4,$1$2")`? Or less precise `.replace( /0?(\d{1,2})\/0?(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})/, "$3,$2,$1")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of only a very simple regex on the split: '/\//g' but even that is overkill when you want to split on a string/char.

This is not much shorter than yours, but very much clearer:

```js
let date = "04/07/2019"
 .split("/")   // ["04","07","2019]
 .map(n => +n) // [4,7,2019]
 .reverse()    // [2019,7,4]
 .join(",");   // "2019,7,4"

console.log(date)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `(\d{2})` subpatterns to match days and months can be replaced with `(?:0?(\d)|(\d{2}))` pattern that matches either an optional `0` followed with a digit that is captured into one group, or matches any two digits and captures them into another group, and when replacing, just use two backreferences to these groups (one of them will always be empty and the other one will hold some text).

```
s = s.replace(/(?:0?(\d)|(\d{2}))\/(?:0?(\d)|(\d{2}))\/(\d{4})/, "$5,$3$4,$1$2");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xVF2mg/1).

To match the whole string, add anchors - if necessary:

```
/^(?:0?(\d)|(\d{2}))\/(?:0?(\d)|(\d{2}))\/(\d{4})$/
```

If matched in a longer text, try word boundaries (if not glued to letters, other digits or underscores), and use `g` modifier to replace all occurrences:

```
/\b(?:0?(\d)|(\d{2}))\/(?:0?(\d)|(\d{2}))\/(\d{4})\b/g
```

See JS demo:

```js
var rx = /(?:0?(\d)|(\d{2}))\/(?:0?(\d)|(\d{2}))\/(\d{4})/;
var repl = "$5,$3$4,$1$2";
console.log("04/07/2019".replace(rx, repl));
console.log("22/08/2019".replace(rx, repl));
console.log("10/10/2019".replace(rx, repl));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the date and month zeros are immediately followed by a number then a forward slash, so you can exploit that:

```js
console.log(
    "04/07/2019".replace(/0(?=\d\/)/g, '')
)
```

Comment: date comes with `zero` - please check

Comment: But does not reorder

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var date = d =>  d.replace( /(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$3/$2/$1").replace(/(?<=\/)0/g, '').split('/').join(',');

   console.log(date("04/07/2019"));
   console.log(date("20/07/2019"));
   console.log(date("20/10/2019"));
```

Comment: `/(?<=\/)0/g` seems like overkill

Answer (score 0):

To fix yours, you would need to replace leading zeros so match /0 instead of just 0.

```js
var date = "04/07/2019".replace(/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/, "$3/$2/$1").replace(/\/0/g, '/').split('/').join(',');
console.log(date); // 219,7,4 !!?
```

Personally I would just change the reg exp to ignore the leading zeros.

```js
console.log("04/07/2019".match(/[1-9]\d{0,3}/g).reverse().join(","))
```

Comment: @mplungjan looked at the edit above, I actually started to write a map, but deleted it. lol

Comment: Yours IS the shortest by 3 chars

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```js
const replace = date => date.replace(/0?(\d+?)\/0?(\d+?)\/(\d+)/, '$3,$2,$1');

console.log(replace('04/07/2019'));
console.log(replace('20/07/2019'));
console.log(replace('20/10/2019'));
```